# MariaDB really slow queries regarding Joins of Joins of Joins

Tags: mysql, performance, join, mariadb, query-performance

I'm attaching the Schema of the database.
[image]
I have strong performance problems when the table Metrics has several technologies and parameters due to the long a full of joins SQL queries that I need to generate to properly access to them. A worker suggested to migrate to MongoDB, but I want to be sure that there isn't a better solution within MariaDB. A sample of the query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT metric.id, a2.xplotvarvalue, metric.joules, metric.seconds, metadata.data 
    FROM metric 
    JOIN concern ON concern.id=metric.idc AND concern.name = 'Security' 
    JOIN design ON design.id=metric.idd AND design.name = 'Cryptography' 
    JOIN datatype ON datatype.id=metric.iddt AND datatype.name = 'String'  
    JOIN operation ON operation.id=metric.ido AND operation.name = 'KeyGeneration'  
    JOIN technologymetric ON technologymetric.idm=metric.id 
JOIN (SELECT idm FROM technologymetric JOIN technology ON technology.id = technologymetric.idt AND technology.name = 'AIAK') AS a0 
ON a0.idm = technologymetric.idm 
JOIN (SELECT idm FROM technologymetric JOIN technology ON technology.id = technologymetric.idt AND technology.name = 'DSA') AS a1 
ON a1.idm = technologymetric.idm  
    JOIN technology ON technology.id=technologymetric.idt 
    JOIN parametervaluemetric ON parametervaluemetric.idm=metric.id 
    JOIN parametervalue ON parametervalue.id=parametervaluemetric.idpv 
JOIN (SELECT idm, parametervalue.value AS xplotvarvalue FROM parametervaluemetric 
JOIN parametervalue ON parametervalue.id=parametervaluemetric.idpv 
JOIN parameter ON parameter.id = parametervalue.idp AND parameter.name = 'KeySize' AND parametervalue.value <= 1024)
 AS a2 ON a2.idm = parametervaluemetric.idm  JOIN parameter ON parameter.id=parametervalue.idp 
    JOIN metadata ON metadata.id=metric.idm ORDER BY metadata.data, FIELD('parameter.name','KeySize')
```

EDIT1: The result-set number of rows is undefined, usually 1, but depends on VALUE in 'AND parametervalue.value < VALUE'. The result-set is not affecting performance. If I don't use DISTINCT, the result-set is doubled (i.e.: It returns two times the same row). The main slowdown its linked with the parameters, one is ok, if I have three for the same metric it can take 3 minutes to return one row. I think that the culprit are the two many-to-many tables between parameter and metric. What we store are systems configurations (for example a data-center, a web sever, an Android App) with their consumption in joules and the runtime.

Comment: Queries about performance should atleast have the output from `EXPLAIN [query]` and profiling the query with type ALL might also be usefull https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/show-profile/

Comment: The biggest problem i think is `DISTINCT metric.id, a2.xplotvarvalue, metric.joules, metric.seconds, metadata.data` because it needs a temporary memory (might change to disk if the data becomes to large) table to resolve this data..

Comment: Please consider making an [edit] to your question so we, and you, can see all the join operations without scrolling horizontally. Please read this, and pay special attention to the section on query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Please [edit] your question to provide more details. How many rows do you expect in your result set? Why `DISTINCT`? It isn't cheap as @RaymondNijland pointed out. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Ok, I've tried to make it clearer. Thank you

Comment: It's really hard to figure this out for a stranger. It seems some tables have many rows and others are small reference tables. Which tables have many rows?  Is a shorter version of the query possible?  Among the tables with many rows, how are they already indexed? What does `EXPLAIN` show you?  BTW, there's no magic that makes complex queries faster with other DBMS tech.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern can be especially slow:

```
JOIN ( SELECT ... ) ON ...
JOIN ( SELECT ... ) ON ...
```

Find some other way to formulate the query.

There is such a thing as "over-normalization".

Consider using `ENUM` instead of normalization.  This would greatly increase the ability to provide a useful index.

"Key-value", aka EAV, schema is problematic.  Rethink whether you really need it.  If you must keep EAV, then follow the tips [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta).  More on [*EAV*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav).

Hiding indexed columns inside function calls prevents use of an index.

After you have moved in some of those directions, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT` to get further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

As Rick mentioned, MySQL / MariaDB can't optimize several subqueries joined in the FROM clause (some improvement was made around MySQL 5.7, but not enough).

Therefore, I would recommend modifying that pattern by extracting the relevant subqueries to temporary tables, which can be indexed for faster search.

Before we start - general note about the index creation commands: It's possible that some of the ALTER statements won't work as is, because I'm not aware of the types of the fields. In some cases, you will have to modify them a bit by letting the database know about the length of the columns (for example in TEXT columns).

First, we'll create indexes to make sure the main query will run as quickly as possible. This should be done only once (and hopefully I didn't miss anything):

```
ALTER TABLE `concern` ADD INDEX `concern_idx_name_id` (`name`, `id`);
ALTER TABLE `datatype` ADD INDEX `datatype_idx_name_id` (`name`, `id`); 
ALTER TABLE `design` ADD INDEX `design_idx_name_id` (`name`, `id`);
ALTER TABLE `metadata` ADD INDEX `metadata_idx_id_data` (`id`, `data`); 
ALTER TABLE `metric` ADD INDEX `metric_idx_idc_idd_iddt_ido_id_idm` (`idc`, `idd`, `iddt`, `ido`, `id`, `idm`);
ALTER TABLE `operation` ADD INDEX `operation_idx_name_id` (`name`, `id`); 
ALTER TABLE `parameter` ADD INDEX `parameter_idx_id` (`id`); ALTER TABLE `parametervalue` ADD INDEX `parametervalue_idx_id_idp` (`id`, `idp`);
ALTER TABLE `parametervaluemetric` ADD INDEX `parametervaluemetric_idx_idm_idpv` (`idm`, `idpv`);
ALTER TABLE `technology` ADD INDEX `technology_idx_id` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `technologymetric` ADD INDEX `technologymetric_idx_idm_idt` (`idm`, `idt`);
ALTER TABLE `technology` ADD INDEX `technology_idx_name_id` (`name`, `id`); 
ALTER TABLE `technologymetric` ADD INDEX `technologymetric_idx_idt_idm` (`idt`, `idm`);
ALTER TABLE `technology` ADD INDEX `technology_idx_name_id` (`name`, `id`); 
ALTER TABLE `technologymetric` ADD INDEX `technologymetric_idx_idt_idm` (`idt`, `idm`);
ALTER TABLE `parameter` ADD INDEX `parameter_idx_name_id` (`name`, `id`); 
ALTER TABLE `parametervalue` ADD INDEX `parametervalue_idx_id_idp_value` (`id`, `idp`, `value`);
ALTER TABLE `parametervaluemetric` ADD INDEX `parametervaluemetric_idx_idpv_idm` (`idpv`, `idm`);
```

Now comes the part which should be done for every query execution:

1. Create the temporary tables.
2. Create the indexes for the temporary tables.
3. Run the main query.

Let's start with creating the relevant temporary tables:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp1 AS SELECT
        technologymetric.idm 
    FROM
        technologymetric 
    JOIN
        technology 
            ON technology.id = technologymetric.idt 
            AND technology.name = 'AIAK';

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp2 AS SELECT
        technologymetric.idm 
    FROM
        technologymetric 
    JOIN
        technology 
            ON technology.id = technologymetric.idt 
            AND technology.name = 'DSA';

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp3 AS SELECT
        parametervaluemetric.idm,
        parametervalue.value AS xplotvarvalue 
    FROM
        parametervaluemetric 
    JOIN
        parametervalue 
            ON parametervalue.id = parametervaluemetric.idpv 
    JOIN
        parameter 
            ON parameter.id = parametervalue.idp 
            AND parameter.name = 'KeySize' 
            AND parametervalue.value <= 1024;
```

Now let's create the indexes for the temporary tables:

```
ALTER TABLE `temp1` ADD INDEX `temp1_idx_idm` (`idm`);
ALTER TABLE `temp2` ADD INDEX `temp2_idx_idm` (`idm`);
ALTER TABLE `temp3` ADD INDEX `temp3_idx_idm_xplotvarvalue` (`idm`, `xplotvarvalue`);
```

And now you can run this transformed main query:

```
SELECT
        DISTINCT metric.id,
        a2.xplotvarvalue,
        metric.joules,
        metric.seconds,
        metadata.data 
    FROM
        metric 
    JOIN
        concern 
            ON concern.id = metric.idc 
            AND concern.name = 'Security' 
    JOIN
        design 
            ON design.id = metric.idd 
            AND design.name = 'Cryptography' 
    JOIN
        datatype 
            ON datatype.id = metric.iddt 
            AND datatype.name = 'String' 
    JOIN
        operation 
            ON operation.id = metric.ido 
            AND operation.name = 'KeyGeneration' 
    JOIN
        technologymetric 
            ON technologymetric.idm = metric.id 
    JOIN
        temp1 AS a0 
            ON a0.idm = technologymetric.idm 
    JOIN
        temp2 AS a1 
            ON a1.idm = technologymetric.idm 
    JOIN
        technology 
            ON technology.id = technologymetric.idt 
    JOIN
        parametervaluemetric 
            ON parametervaluemetric.idm = metric.id 
    JOIN
        parametervalue 
            ON parametervalue.id = parametervaluemetric.idpv 
    JOIN
        temp3 AS a2 
            ON a2.idm = parametervaluemetric.idm 
    JOIN
        parameter 
            ON parameter.id = parametervalue.idp 
    JOIN
        metadata 
            ON metadata.id = metric.idm 
    ORDER BY
        metadata.data,
        FIELD('parameter.name',
        'KeySize')
```